# Java HSBC API payment gateway

Tags: java, xml

I am looking for a Java HSBC API payment gateway script.i developed it in php but coming 
to java howcan i do that.below is the php code i used

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = ‘https://www.secure-epayments.apixml.hsbc.com’;
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data_will_go_here);
ob_start();
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HTTPConnection Class, this might help!

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html